# email sent from salesforce but not received but test delivery emails are received

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

email sent from salesforce are not received but test delivery emails are received, this is happening only on sandbox environment and works fine in production

checked Deliverability and other troubleshooting techniques, all are fine. even the email log shows status as delivered, but emails are not received. its not in SPAM, JUNK and inbox folders

Comment: Any email addresses or just your company's? Are you using email relay or the messages go straight out of SF? Maybe there's antivirus or something before it hits your mailbox. Have you talked with IT whether they whitelist emails maybe. By IP or domain. Maybe the sandbox is migrated to Hyperforce?

Comment: Yes, thats right, I also created a SF ticket for which they replied that Email is being sent out from our sandboxes but the server is bouncing those emails back. need to reach out to IT Support to whitelist those sandbox domains and then once its notified, emails should start flowing.

Comment: Nice. If you make any progress it'd be great if you can answer your own question. I'd happily upvote it. With the Hyperforce migrations I think more people can be hit with "emails stopped working" and this would be a valuable resource to them. In general it's better to whitelist by domains than by IPs...